# Mathematical expression for long run costs curves

Tags: marginal, long-run

I struggle to find formal mathematical expressions for long run average costs and long run marginal costs. All ressources I see take a finite number of short run average costs and draw the envelop curve to it. Is this really the right way to define it formally ? Since there is a finite number of curves, the envelop is not well-defined right ? So is it implicit that there are infinitely many short run average costs so that there is only one possible envelop curve : the LRAC ?

The LRMC is then the derivative of this curve. Is there a formal mathematical expression for theses curves ?

Comment: A related discussion is given here: https://economics.stackexchange.com/questions/53166/where-does-the-short-run-and-long-run-costs-intersect-if-k-is-fixed/53183#53183

Comment: You can also check this playlist: https://youtube.com/playlist?list=PLUJGfL_499TJ4xlOvpKeAqo4M5xYkq6wi